# EF Core 2.1 Class Inheritance Issues

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-core

I get the error `The property or navigation 'BankAccount' cannot be added to the entity type 'ClubTreasurer.Models.Person' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'ClubTreasurer.Models.Person'.` when I try to apply a migration.

I tried restarting, cleaning and rebuilding. Dropped and recreated database, deleted old migrations.

I thought TPH was the issue so I assigned them all their own tables:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccount>().ToTable("BankAccount");
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person");
```

My 2 classes and the shared base class:

```
namespace ClubTreasurer.Models
{
    public class BankAccount : BaseModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string IBAN { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }

        public ICollection<BankTransaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ClubTreasurer.Models
{
    public class Person : BaseModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string FullName { get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; } }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        public ICollection<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ClubTreasurer.Models
{
    public class BaseModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LastModifiedBy")]
        public string LastModifiedById { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
        public string CreatedById { get; set; }

        public IdentityUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public IdentityUser LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I know I could just drop the inheritance and add my shadow props to each class but that seems wasteful.

**Edit** I tried dropping the inheritence and moved the audit properties to each class but still get the same error message

**Post Edit Edit** Seems like I didn't delete enough when it came to past migrations.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: @jarlih because SQL determines what EF does with the inheritence

Comment: If there hasn't been any news I missed, EF Core up to this time (EF Core 2.1) doesn't support inheritance models other than TPH

Comment: And sorry, but your model also makes no sense at all. What's the connection between BankAccount and Person? Its two completely different things, why would you want to inherit and save that in the same table in the first place? You use inheritance for similar models, person -> employer -> manager or similar

Comment: @Tseng you might want to give Microsoft a shout and tell them that their language makes no sense so considering everything inherits from Object

Comment: Object is explicitly excluded by EF Core :P You can also ignore the inheritance, theres something in the docs about it, i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance `You can use .HasBaseType((Type)null) to remove an entity type from the hierarchy.` or correctly marking the baseclass as **ABSTRACT**, since abstract classes can't be instanciated, there won't be a need for a discriminator or to treat it as a separate entity

Comment: @Tseng I tried your suggestion but still get the same error

Comment: @rory can you share code of your DBContext class OnConfiguring method if there is any?

Comment: Don't think it's behind your issue here, but you should fix it regardless: `BaseModel` should be abstract. The way you have it now, EF will track `BaseModel` as it's own entity type (along with an associated table).